# input field increment and decrement behave remove

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

how to remove built-in increment and decrement buttons or behave of input field type: number

Remove built-in increment and decrement buttons or behave of input field type: number without change input type

i have tried appearance none class of css but no working this class for remove behave

```
appearance-none
```

Answer (score 2):

The `appearance-none` class in CSS is typically used to remove the default styling associated with form elements, but it might not be supported across all browsers for the input element with `type="number"`. The appearance of the increment and decrement buttons on a number input is often controlled by the browser itself and may not be easily styled or removed.

use a combination of CSS and JavaScript to hide or disable the default increment and decrement buttons

```js
document.getElementById('myNumberInput').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.key === 'ArrowUp' || e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
#myNumberInput::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
#myNumberInput::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#myNumberInput {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myNumberInput" />
```

Note : This CSS and JavaScript combination should work in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

But why you need input of type number then if you don't want to use the increment and decrement button. If it is because you want user to restrict only writing number in the input box then better use below code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Numeric Text Input</title>
  <style>
    input {
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <label for="numericInput">Numeric Input:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="numericInput"
    name="numericInput"
    oninput="handleInput(this)"
  />

  <script>
    function handleInput(input) {
      const value = input.value;
      // Remove non-numeric characters using a regular expression
      input.value = value.replace(/\D/g, ''); // \D matches any non-digit character
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```